# matlab keep nan values

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a huge matrix and I need all the information in it. The contents are mostly numbers but some of them are like "V11.7" or "E111.7". When I import this matrix, the elements containing alphabet are considered as NaN. Is there any way so that I can keep the value of these cells and prevent them from becoming NaN?

Currently, I am using this code to import data:

```
[~, txt, raw, dateNums] = xlsread('FileName','Sheet1','','',@convertSpreadsheetDates);
```

Since It is a huge matrix, I don't want anything to be manual, so the code find the header of each column and read the data in it (instead of saying go to column 21 and read the data in it):

```
ColName = 'A1';

DataInColumn = find(strcmp(Header,ColName));

DataInColumnRaw = data(2:end,DataInColumn );
```

A part of data in this column is: `{12, 302.58, V45.7, 5.8, E111.87}`. The code import them like: `{12, 302.58, NaN, 5.8, NaN}`. But I need to keep the value of these NaN cells.

Help me please.

Comment: How are you importing this matrix? Could you edit your question to show the code you are using?

Comment: As @JonasHeidelberg says, please can you provide an example. Generally you need to provide an example of what you're doing now, the result you get and the result you want. Also, if you're importing from a file it helps if you can include an example file as well.

Comment: Please let me know if you need other clarification.

Comment: When do you get the `NaN`? Surely `raw` has no `NaN`s, yet you never use `raw` again?

Comment: I get NaN in "DataInColumnRaw". I did not notice "raw". I just checked "raw", It has NaN like "DataInColumnRaw".

Comment: What format is the file you're importing? Is it an `.xls` or `.csv` or something? Essentially you need to import the data as strings, then process the strings to remove the letters and finally convert the strings to numbers. If you confirm the file format we should be able to help you do this.